# Idiosyncratic characterizations of $\ell^p$, for $p\not=1,2,\infty$

Tags: banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

Do there exist, either in the literature or in folklore, theorems
that characterize some particular $\ell^p$ space(s) ($p\not=1,2,\infty$)?

Such a theorem should reveal the particular space(s) as somehow idiosyncratic,
in the sense that no obvious modification of the characterization works
for general $\ell^p$ spaces.

Thus it would *not* be interesting here to learn, say,
that $\ell^3$ alone has a dual isomorphic to $\ell^{3/2}$; 
obviously this just specializes a general fact from the theory of all
the $\ell^p$'s.

Comment: This is too cheap to qualify as more than a comment, but $p={\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$ is the only case where $\ell^p$ is dual to `$\ell^{p^2}$`.

Comment: @Aaron Perhaps if there were some natural *abstract* connection between $\ell^p$ and $\ell^{p^2}$, you'd have a winner.

Answer (score 12):

1. Littlewood's $4/3$-inequality singles out $\ell^{4/3}$.

   Namely, given a real valued array $\hat{a}=(\hat a_{m,n}:(m,n)\in\mathbb N^2)$, the norm $\|\hat a\|_{\ell_p}$ is finite for all $\hat a$ such that 
   $$\sup \left\{\left|\sum\limits_{m\in\mathcal M,n\in\mathcal N}\hat a_{m,n}x_my_n\right|:x_m,y_n\in[-1,1],\mathcal M,\mathcal N\mbox{ are finite}\right\} < \infty$$
   if and only if $p\geq 4/3$.
2. The second example is somewhat tangential to the question but I find it worth mentioning. It is concerned with the peculiar asymptotics of $L^4$-norms of the Hermite functions (see, e.g., [*Lectures on Hermite and Laguerre expansions*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=I9Kkb4SnTw0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=lectures+on+hermite+and+laguerre+expansions&source=bl&ots=kL4N2qXmal&sig=ZJPEHMcU4J_HvWaZ74v0q2z95TA&hl=en&ei=BucFTZTQEITr4gbd29i6Cg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Thangavelu, Lemma 1.5.2).

   > **Proposition.** As $n\to\infty$ the Hermite functions satisfy the estimates 
   >   $$\|h_n\|_{p}\sim\begin{cases} n^{\frac{1}{2p}-\frac{1}{4}}, &  1\leq p< \infty, \\\ \\\ n^{-\frac{1}{8}}\log n, &  p=4, \\\  \\\ n^{-\frac{1}{6p}-\frac{1}{12}}, & 4 < p\leq \infty. \end{cases} $$
   >   Here $a_n\sim b_n$  means $a_n=O(b_n)$ and $b_n=O(a_n)$.

Comment: Interesting, and close to what I want, but this doesn't so much single out the space    $\ell^{4/3}$ as single out the number $4/3$. If it could be combined with a condition characterizing  $\ell^p$'s for  $p\leq 4/3$, that would be perfect.

Comment: Also, if you use the higher dimensional version by Bohnenblust and Hille, you can also similarly characterize all numbers $p = \frac{2m}{m+1}$ for $m\in \mathbb{N}$. (The inequality is
$$ \|\hat{a}\|_{\ell^p(\mathbb{N}^m)} \leq 2^{(m-1)/2} \|\hat{a}\| $$
where on the RHS is $\sup \hat{a}(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ with each $x_i\in \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$.)

Comment: Dear Andrey: I got confused by where you put the if and only if. Sorry. Deleted the irrelevant comments. 

Comment: Dear Willie, many thanks for your comment. 

Comment: In fact there is nothing special in Littlewood's inequality. It is a manifistation of general result of Kwapien: any operator from $\mathcal{L}_1$ space to $\mathcal{L}_p$ space is $(r,1)$-summing for $r^{-1}=1-|p^{-1}-2^{-1}|$ and $p>1$. For details see page 208 in Absolutely Summing Operators by Joe Diestel

Answer (score 6):

The following theorem is due to Plotkin and Rudin and characterizes $p \neq 2,4,6,\dots.$

**Theorem:** (Plotkin-Rudin): Let $0< p< \infty$ and $p \neq 2,4,6,\dots$. Let $(\Omega,\mu)$ and $(\Omega',\nu)$ be two
probability measure spaces. Let finally $n$ be a positive integer and $f_1, \dots f_n
\in L_p(\mu)$, $g_1, \dots g_n \in L_p(\nu)$.

Assume that for all complex numbers $z_1, \dots z_n \in \mathbb C$,

$$\int |1 + z_1 f_1 + \dots z_n f_n |^p d \mu = \int |1 + z_1 g_1 + \dots z_n g_n|^p d \nu.$$

Then $(f_1 ,\dots f_n)$ and $(g_1 ,\dots g_n)$ form two equimeasurable
families. This means that the ${\mathbb R}^n$-valued random
variables $(f_1 ,\dots f_n)$ and $(g_1 ,\dots g_n)$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Are there easy counterexamples in the remaining cases?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps if you look at applications to other domains and you admit the Lebesgue space $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$... The space $L^n(\mathbb R^n)$ is critical for Navier-Stokes in space dimension $n$. For instance a theorem of T. Kato says that if the initial data is small in $L^3(\mathbb R^3)$, then the Navier-Stokes equation for an incompressible fluid admits a unique solution, global in time. Removing the smallness assumption is worth a million dollars. The exponent $p=3$ is the only one for which such a result holds true.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a true characterization of some $\ell^p$ space (an if and only if) I suspect no example satisfies your demands (probably it's only my ignorance :). There are of course inequalities which are known to be true for special values of $p$ and are an open problem for other values, at least for $L^p$ (and a discrete analogue seems reasonable). Best candidate for this kind of inequalities is $p=4$ since the norm is the square of a square and can be represented in a fairly reasonable way using Fourier transform and convolutions. This method allows to prove e.g. Zygmund's inequality
$$ \|\sum c_{n}e^{i(n^2t+nx)}\|^2_{L^4(\mathbb{T}^2)}\le C \sum|c_n|^2 $$
for $L^4$ on $\mathbb{T}^2_{t,x}=[0,2\pi]^2$.

Comment: @Piero. Isn't it a special case of a Strichartz inequality ?

Comment: @Denis: yes indeed, it is the 1D Strichartz inequality for the Scroedinger equation, and it was proved by Zygmund around 1950

Comment: P.S. notice that the other Strichartz inequalities are for a $L^p_tL^q_x$ norm with p different from q.

Answer (score 0):

$p$-stability singles out $0 < p \le 2$. Specifically, there is no probability distribution $P$ such that the linear combination $\sum^n a_i X_i$ is distributed as $\|a\|_p Y$, where $X_1 ... X_n$ and $Y$ are random variables distributed according to $P$, if $p$ is not in the range $(0, 2]$.

For $p = 0.5, 1, 2$ these distributions have closed-form expressions.

(note: updated to reflect Gideon Schectman's comment)

Comment: There are p-stable distributions for all 0<p≤2. I think this is usually attributed to Paul Levy. You can find this in many books. I particularly like the construction in Chung's A course in probability theory.

Comment: Ah correct. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: A functional analytic version and amplification of this is that if $p<2$, then $\ell_r$ embeds isometrically isomorphically into $L_p$ for $p\le r\le 2$, while if $r$ is not in this range, then $\ell_r$ does not embed even isomorphically into $L_p$.

Comment: what is an 'isomorphic' embedding ? 

Comment: An isomorphic embedding is a linear homeomorphism into.